# Connect MySQL database with webservice

Tags: php, html, mysql, web-services

I want to connect a MySQL database to a webservice. I followed a tutorial, but it does not work. I have no idea, why it's not workiing. The table is built, but it should be filled with the vaues from the database. I just want to diplay it. Does anybaody have an idea? This is my src-code:

```
enter code here
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php
       $mysqlhost="localhost"; // MySQL-Host angeben

       $mysqluser="root"; // MySQL-User angeben

       $mysqlpwd="webservice"; // Passwort angeben

       $mysqldb="**********"; // Gewuenschte Datenbank angeben



       $connection=mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die ("Verbindungsversuch                    fehlgeschlagen");



        mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Konnte die Datenbank nicht waehlen."); 
        mysql_select_db( MYSQL_DATENBANK ) or die("Auswahl der Datenbank fehlgeschlagen");

      $sql="SELECT * FROM car";

     $adressen_query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Anfrage nicht erfolgreich");
    ?>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3" border="1">

    <tr>

    <td>ID</td>

    <td>Producer</td>

    <td>Type</td>

    <td>BJ</td>

    <td>HP</td>

    <td>Mileage</td>

    </tr>

    <?php

    while ($adr = mysql_fetch_array($adressen_query)){

    ?>

    <tr>

    <td><?=$adr['ID']?></td>

    <td><?=$adr['Producer']?></td>

    <td><?=$adr['Type']?></td>

    <td><?=$adr['BJ']?></td>

    <td><?=$adr['HP']?></td>

    <td><?=$adr['mileage']?></td>


    </tr>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Is the web service on the same server as your website?  If not, `localhost` needs to be changed to the URL or IP address of the hosting database server.

Comment: but if you used `mysql_*` functions, use mysql_error to handle error, look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php`, @Maerlyn is right, use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: @Maerlyn Is there any possibility to use mysql_* functions in MySQL 5.4? Is this my problem or is it another? Can't I use these functions in general or is it just better not to use them because they are no longer maintained?

Comment: They are still in php (will be there in 5.5 too), they're just not recommended, partly because they're difficult to be used properly, partly because they are no longer maintained. PDO and MySQLi are far superior alternatives, look into those.